# Trying to pass the dropdownlist value to parameter on a submit button when selected using MVC C#

Tags: c#, sql, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a stored procedure linked to the model, and I am trying to get the Value to the parameter based on the dropdown-list when submit. I can get the Final Value when I put the string in the parameter. However, I want the Final Value based on the dropdown-list on select using submit button. How can I pass the selected value from the dropdown-list to the parameter. My parameter is GetWACC() @oplocation, @Industry, @Date). I try to pass the list to the parameter and converted ToString() but it doesn't work. Please help.

Thanks a lot.

Here is my HomeController:

```
 public ActionResult WACC()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your WACC page.";

        //Set Industry : Later make it DB-Driven
        //List<SelectListItem> lstIndustry = new List<SelectListItem>() {
        //    new SelectListItem {Text = "Financials", Value = "1"},
        //  new SelectListItem {Text = "Real Estate", Value = "2"},
        //};



        // Pre-set values
        var objWACC = new WACC();

        objWACC.ValuationDate = new DateTime(2018, 11, 20);
        //objWACC.IndustryList = lstIndustry;
        objWACC.IndustryList = WACC_Lib.GetIndustry();
        //objWACC.IndustrySelected = 1;
         objWACC.LocationList = WACC_Lib.GetOpLocations();
        //objWACC.LocationSelected = 1;
        DateTime waccdate = objWACC.ValuationDate;
        string indlist = objWACC.IndustryList.ToString();
        string loclist = objWACC.LocationList.ToString();
        objWACC.FairValue = WACC_Lib.GetWACC(loclist, indlist, waccdate);



        // Redirect to WACC page    
        return View(objWACC);
    }
```

Here is my WACC Contoller:

```
public class WACCController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetWACC")] // for testing, F5 and change the link to http://localhost:54192/API/WACC/GetWACC?strOpLocation=Hong%20%Kong&strIndustry=Financials&strIniDate=2017-12-31&strValDate=2018-12-31 , the port no may be different (no "HOME")
    public double GetWACC(string strOpLocation, string strIndustry, DateTime ValDate)
    {
        double dblResult = 0.0;

        try
        {
            dblResult = BDODataLib.WACC_Lib.GetWACC(strOpLocation, strIndustry, ValDate);
        }
        catch
        {
            dblResult = -2.0;
        }            

        return dblResult;
    }
}
```

}

Here is my Model:

```
public class WACC
{
    [Key]
    [Display(Name = "Industry")]
    //public string Industry { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> IndustryList { get; set; }
    public string IndustrySelected { get; set; }

   // public int LocID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Location")]
    public List<SelectListItem> LocationList { get; set; }

    public string LocationSelected { get; set; }


    [Display(Name = "Valualtion Date")]
    public DateTime ValuationDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "WACC")]
    public double FairValue { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my View:

```
        <table class='wacctable'>


            <tr>
                <td style="background-color:lightgrey">@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.IndustryList)</td>
                @*<td>@Html.DropDownList("lstIndustry", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["lstIndustry"],1)</td>*@
                @*<td style="width: 200px">@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.IndustrySelected, Model.IndustryList, "--Select One--", new {onchange = "document.getElementById('TheForm').submit();" })</td>*@
                <td style="width: 200px">@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.LocID, new SelectList (Model.IndustryList, "Value", "Text"), "--Select One--")</td>

                @*<td>@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Industry, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["lstIndustry"])</td>*@
                @*<td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Industry)</td>*@
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="background-color:lightgrey">@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.LocationList)</td>
                @*<td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.LocationList)</td>*
                @*<td>@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.LocationSelected, Model.LocationList, "--Select One--", new { @class = "abc", onchange = "document.getElementById('TheForm').submit();" })</td>*@
                <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.LocID, new SelectList (Model.LocationList, "Value", "Text"), "--Select One--", new { @class = "abc" })</td>


                @*<td>@Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.LocationSelected, new SelectList(Model.LocationList, "Value"), htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", id = "Location",style = "length: 180px;" })</td>*@

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="background-color:lightgrey">@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.ValuationDate)</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ValuationDate, string.Format("{0:d}", Model.ValuationDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")), new { @class = "date-picker", type = "date" })</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="background-color:lightgrey">@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.FairValue)</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FairValue, new { @class = "width: 180px;" })</td>
            </tr>

        </table>
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value='Submit' />




    }
</div>
```

here is how it looks like when i pass the parameter

[The parameter return this "System.Collection.Generic.List"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OMNN.png)

Here is the view looks like:

[This is how the dropdownlist looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FfLa.png)

Comment: `objWACC.LocationList` is of type `List<SelectListItem>` so result of `objWACC.LocationList.ToString()` will be `System.Collections.Generic.List....`. You should select only on item from the list and pass its value to the method.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya thanks for the comment. Is there any examples that you can give me. Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing list LocationList to api method.

objWACC.FairValue = WACC_Lib.GetWACC(loclist, indlist, waccdate);

while you should pass selected one location to api method as below:

objWACC.FairValue = WACC_Lib.GetWACC(objWACC.LocationSelected, indlist, waccdate);

As i see your view code and model, you are binding locID with location dropdown while you should bind LocationSelected with location dropdown and you will get selected value in LocationSelected model property. it seems you are doing experiment and forget to uncomment required line.need some modification in 2nd row of table view please uncomment below line :

```
@*<td>@Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.LocationSelected, new SelectList(Model.LocationList, "Value"), htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", id = "Location",style = "length: 180px;" })</td>*@
```

Comment below line :

```
 <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.LocID, new SelectList (Model.LocationList, "Value", "Text"), "--Select One--", new { @class = "abc" })</td>
```